# Popup in MAUI cropped when including a multiline label

Tags: c#, xaml, maui, maui-community-toolkit

I'm trying to generate custom popups in .Net MAUI to give some informations and messages in my application. I'm meeting an issue, when the text message displayed in my popup is longer than one line, the popup gets cropped and thebuttons at the bottom aren't fully displayed.

For example :

Single line label:

[image]

Multi line label:

[image]

The XAML code of my Popup

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<mct:Popup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
           xmlns:mct="clr-namespace:CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views;assembly=CommunityToolkit.Maui"
           xmlns:utils="clr-namespace:MauiUtils"
           x:Class="MauiUtils.Popups.DialogPopup"
           CanBeDismissedByTappingOutsideOfPopup="True">
    <Grid MinimumWidthRequest="350" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Background="Transparent">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Background="Transparent">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <utils:ImageTintColor x:Name="PopupIcon" Grid.Column="1" IsVisible="False" StyleClass="Popup" MaximumHeightRequest="40" MaximumWidthRequest="40" Margin="0, 5, 0, 5"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="2" x:Name="PopupTitle" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold" Text="" MaximumWidthRequest="350" StyleClass="Popup"/>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Label x:Name="PopupContent" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="Medium" Margin="10" Text=""  StyleClass="Popup" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
        </Grid>
         
        <Grid Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,0,0,10" Background="Transparent">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="TogglableColumn" Width="1*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button x:Name="ConfirmBtn" Grid.Column="0" Text="" HorizontalOptions="Fill" Margin="20, 0, 20, 0" FontSize="Medium" Clicked="ComfirmBtn_Clicked" StyleClass="Popup"/>
            <Button x:Name="CancelBtn" Grid.Column="1" Text="" HorizontalOptions="Fill" Margin="20, 0, 20, 0" FontSize="Medium" Clicked="CancelBtn_Clicked" IsVisible="True" StyleClass="Popup"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</mct:Popup>
```

The associated C# code :

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace MauiUtils.Popups;

public partial class DialogPopup : Popup
{
    readonly Action ConfirmMethod;
    readonly Action CancelMethod;

    public DialogPopup(Action _ConfirmMethod = null, Action _CancelMethod = null, string _Title = "Dialog", string _IconSource = "", string _Content = "Lorem ipsum", bool _ShowCancelBtn = true, string _ConfirmBtnLabel = "Yes", string _CancelBtnLabel = "No", bool _TapOutDismiss = true)
    {
        ConfirmMethod = _ConfirmMethod;
        CancelMethod = _CancelMethod;
        this.CanBeDismissedByTappingOutsideOfPopup = _TapOutDismiss;

        InitializeComponent();

        PopupTitle.Text = _Title;

        if (_IconSource != "")
        {
            try
            {
                PopupIcon.Source = _IconSource;
                PopupIcon.IsVisible = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }

        PopupContent.Text = _Content;
        ConfirmBtn.Text = _ConfirmBtnLabel;
        CancelBtn.IsVisible = _ShowCancelBtn;
        if (!CancelBtn.IsVisible)
        {
            TogglableColumn.Width = new GridLength(0);
        }
        CancelBtn.Text = _CancelBtnLabel;
    }

    private void ComfirmBtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ConfirmMethod?.Invoke();
        Close();
    }

    private void CancelBtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CancelMethod?.Invoke();
        Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extensive use of `auto`-sizing with [Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/grid)s is discouraged. Since you're only using rows for the outer Grid, you may want to change that to a [VerticalStackLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/verticalstacklayout), which should resolve the layout issue with regards to the multiline label:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<mct:Popup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
           xmlns:mct="clr-namespace:CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views;assembly=CommunityToolkit.Maui"
           xmlns:utils="clr-namespace:MauiUtils"
           x:Class="MauiUtils.Popups.DialogPopup"
           CanBeDismissedByTappingOutsideOfPopup="True">

    <VerticalStackLayout MinimumWidthRequest="350" HorizontalOptions="Fill" Background="Transparent">

        <Grid HorizontalOptions="Fill" Background="Transparent">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <utils:ImageTintColor x:Name="PopupIcon" Grid.Column="1" IsVisible="False" StyleClass="Popup" MaximumHeightRequest="40" MaximumWidthRequest="40" Margin="0, 5, 0, 5"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="2" x:Name="PopupTitle" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold" Text="" MaximumWidthRequest="350" StyleClass="Popup"/>
        </Grid>

        <Grid>
            <Label x:Name="PopupContent" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="Medium" Margin="10" Text="" StyleClass="Popup" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
        </Grid>
         
        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,10" Background="Transparent">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="TogglableColumn" Width="1*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button x:Name="ConfirmBtn" Grid.Column="0" Text="" HorizontalOptions="Fill" Margin="20, 0, 20, 0" FontSize="Medium" Clicked="ComfirmBtn_Clicked" StyleClass="Popup"/>
            <Button x:Name="CancelBtn" Grid.Column="1" Text="" HorizontalOptions="Fill" Margin="20, 0, 20, 0" FontSize="Medium" Clicked="CancelBtn_Clicked" IsVisible="True" StyleClass="Popup"/>
        </Grid>

    </VerticalStackLayout>

</mct:Popup>
```

Alternatively, if you want to stick to a `Grid` on the outside, you could also try changing the values of the row definitions and limit the use of `auto` to a single row or use `*` instead:

```xml
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Or:

```xml
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Also note that the `*AndExpand` LayoutOptions are deprecated in MAUI and will be removed in a future version.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about the `*AndExpand` part, it was here as a tentative to fix my issue but didn't do anything, will know not to use it now.
I gave a try to the `StackLayout` control, and sadly I still have that issue (I  was initially working in a VerticalStackLayout, but I switched to Grid when I met that issue hoping it would solve it).

Comment: Also tried your alternative options with specifying the size of the lines : if I use only one `Auto`, I still meet the same cropping problem, and if I use `*` my Label is cropped to one single line instead of my buttons. It feels like the popup is always resizing as if there was only a single line of text, then tries to force the full text in the label.

Comment: Okay I ended up working this way, with defined sizes for first and third row, and setting up the height of second row dynamically based on the lenght of the text. Not clean, but it does the job so far. Thanks for looking into this !

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue logged in the https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/ repo that the Popup doesn't calculate its window height correctly if its content doesn't explicitly set a height.

Instead of trying to squish the Popup contents into the small window, you can make the window bigger by setting a HeightRequest on the outer Grid. You could get clever and measure the contents first, but since there are fixes in the pipeline I wouldn't complicate it.

See [[BUG] Popup Height & Long Text #1353](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/issues/1353) / [[BUG]? Popup does not wrap content (on Android) #1150](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/issues/1150)

The following should fix this:

- Pull request in review for Android and iOS: [Fix Popup size on Android and iOS #1361](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/pull/1361)
- Pull request merged for Windows: [Fix Windows Popup Position and Size #1350](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/pull/1350)